# Guide to plan a Rails application. From Idea to Prototype?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, entity-relationship

## The Glue..

Last semester I was taught **Ruby** in my programming classes, some about *Entity Relationship Diagrams*, and some *Dataflow*.
I have been going into **Ruby on Rails** lately and I want to use some of my accumulated novice knowledge to develop a site based on a simple idea.
However, I can't seem to find the glue between *Ruby on Rails* and my knowledge from last semester. There are certain specific areas where I'm stuck and keep getting confused:

How can I translate my entities from my diagrams to Rails thinking?
What are the naming conventions or even the translation - is an entity a *Controller*? Or a *Model*?

Let's imagine that I have the following wish:

The web app is an online list, displaying cars which have been stolen from users of the site. A *User* (entity?) should be able to register with user information (*attributes*?), fill-out a form that will create a CarPost(Entity?) with a unique id and reg. number privately viewable in his own post overview, CarPostView (*View*?).

If and when his/hers car gets stolen! (knock on wood), the *User* should be able to *Activate* (*action*?) that *CarPost* to be displayed as stolen at the front page of the website, searchable and readable to all visitors. If the car is returned to the *User*, the *User* should be able to deactivate the *CarPost* and make it invisible again for others, but keep it in his post overview page.

In my head, the:

- User, needs a model?

  - User has attributes, and they are accessed through the View files?
- CarPost, needs a model?

  - CarPost has attributes, and they are accessed through the View files?

Then I need to create some 'actions?' somewhere that can activate/deactivate the *CarPosts*, and establish some relations between them. I think that *relations* is known as *associations* in Rails, correct me - please - if I'm wrong? And those should be in my *Models*?

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Have you gone through the Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl? http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. Try going through that to gain some familiarity with Rails.

Comment: Hi Artin. Thanks for your suggestion. I've gone through a lot of it, but I might have missed something. I have also looked at a lot of other resources, but I think I simply need someone to tell me how this boat rocks before I can grasp it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model):

> In software engineering, an Entity–relationship model (ER model) is a **data model for describing a database in an abstract way**.

Your question:

> What are the naming conventions or even the translation - is an entity a Controller? Model?

The Model layer in Rails *(and all other **M**VC frameworks)* is the abstraction layer between you and the database. Each model typically an "Entity" and relationships in part are described by the associations/relations on the models.

---

From your description, a `User` and `CarPost` would exist as models *(though I'd be inclined to rename `CarPost` something like `Car`)*. You'll have both a `users` and `cars` table in the database for each of these models.

The "actions" in your diagram will in many cases be handled with an action in a Rails controller. This is the **C** in MV**C** - the layer in which your business logic goes. A great example is the "activating" of a `Car`'s listing within your application. This might sit in a `CarsController`'s `activate` action.

---

The "Views" are simply the HTML templates, they're the **V** in M**V**C. This is what the user sees and will interact with in order to tell Rails what they want to do. Again following your example, you might have a view to display a user's car *(Typically a `show` action on your `CarsController`)* and on that same view/template have a link to the `activate` action in your `CarsController`.

*This is admittedly an over-simplified explanation of MVC in relation to your question about ER models. If you are interested in diving in deeper, I suggest googling MVC - the internet is littered with information on it.*

---

You mention in the comments that you've gone through a lot of the Hartl tutorial. I've never read it myself but know it's quite popular around here for people just starting out with Rails. I find it a little difficult to believe you've made it most of the way through the tutorial and are unable to connect the dots between your ER model and the various pieces of Rails' framework. This isn't criticism, but merely pointing out that you should have gotten a lot more out of the tutorial than you seem to have - another go at it might be wise.

Another excellent resource for beginners are the official **[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)**.

Comment: Deefour, I'm not reading it as criticism. I'm reading your answer as a HUGE help. Thanks for the clarifying and answering a lot of my questions. I went through the chapters from 1 to 4 or 5, I think, a while back. But I had so many issues with my environment and caught so many errors, that I eventually gave up. I then found some other resources, followed an online college program, but it was never really clear to me. But, I will definitely take your advice and go back and have a look at his tutorial. Again, thanks a lot for your answer. It all made a little more sense to me now. All the best!

Comment: @Daud, also remember, this site is an amazing resource - one I wish I had when I was in college. Dive into the tutorial and when you get stuck or confused, ask **specific** questions here and you're sure to get the help you need.